# How can I use an XPATH to populate a drop-list in Sitecore WFM?

Tags: xpath, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm using Sitecore 7.5 with Web Forms for Marketers, but I need to create a form that populates from value from an item in sitecore.  For example, I have a country list here:

sitecore/Content/demographics/database/Countries/AD

AD for example is an object for Andorra, so under Countries is a big list of country codes.  However each country code object has a section called Data, which contains 3 fields:  Country, Description, and region.

For each country in the Countries node, I want to populate a drop-list using WFM with the Description.

what would the XPATH be for this? or is it not possible with XPATH to populate the drop-list in WFM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need XPath to do this. Just add a Drop List to the form and you can set the items via the properties of the field. You can pick which field from the item is used to populate the value and text of the drop list:

[image]

1. Select `Drop List` as the field type
2. Click the `...` button to select the items to be used for the list

[image]

3. Select your folder with the items in
4. Pick the fields to use for the `Value` and `Text` properties of the Drop List.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  For some weird reason the field values were not populating the list items on Chrome.  I switched to IE and things are displaying now. I am able to select the appropriate field.